How do you actually evaluate a retrieval system?
Say I have a knowledge base, I splitted it and generated question-answer with qa_generator and filtered it out with a qa_critic, so I have question, answer, and context.
Now while building a rag system (particularly retrieval), I may need to split the knowledge base based on a different chunk size, in that case, how do you measure precision/recall, etc?
One way I can think of is to split into larger chunks during qa generation and smaller chunks during retrieval (in that way we can maintain a parent-child relationship which can be used during evaluation)
